# AWK print every other column, starting from the last column (and next to last column) for N interations (print from right to left)

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Hopefully someone out there in the world can help me, and anyone else with a similar problem, find a simple solution to capturing data. I have spent hours trying a one liner to solve something I thought was a simple problem involving awk, a csv file, and saving the output as a bash variable. In short here's the nut...

The Missions:

1) To output every other column, starting from the LAST COLUMN, with a specific iteration count.

2) To output every other column, starting from NEXT TO LAST COLUMN, with a specific iteration count.

The Data (file.csv):

```
@12@SayWhat@2@4@2.25@3@1.5@1@1@1@3.25
@7@Smarty@9@6@5.25@5@4@4@3@2@3.25
@4@IfYouLike@4@1@.2@1@.5@2@1@3@3.75
@3@LaughingHard@8@8@13.75@8@13@6@8.5@4@6
@10@AtFunny@1@3@.2@2@.5@3@3@5@6.5
@8@PunchLines@7@7@10.25@7@10.5@8@11@6@12.75
```

Desired results for Mission 1:

```
  2@2.25@1.5@1@3.25
  9@5.25@4@3@3.25
  4@.2@.5@1@3.75
  8@13.75@13@8.5@6
  1@.2@.5@3@6.5
  7@10.25@10.5@11@12.75
```

Desired results for Mission 2:

```
  SayWhat@4@3@1@1
  Smarty@6@5@4@2
  IfYouLike@1@1@2@3
  LaughingHard@8@8@6@4
  AtFunny@3@2@3@5
  PunchLines@7@7@8@6
```

My Attempts:

The closes I have come to solving any of the above problems, is an ugly pipe (which is OK for skinning a cat) for Mission 1. However, it doesn't use any declared iterations (which should be 5). Also, I'm completely lost on solving Mission 2.

Any help to simplify the below and solving Mission 2 will be HELLA appreciated!

```
outcome=$( awk 'BEGIN {FS = "@"} {for (i = 0; i <= NF; i += 2) printf ("%s%c", $(NF-i), i + 2 <= NF ? "@" : "\n");}' file.csv | sed 's/@@.*//g' | awk -F@ '{for (i=NF;i>0;i--){printf $i"@"};printf "\n"}' | sed 's/@$//g' | awk -F@ '{$1="";print $0}' OFS=@ | sed 's/^@//g' );
```

Also, if doing a loop for a specific number of iterations is helpful in solving this problem, then magic number is 5. Maybe a solution could be a for-loop that is counting from right to left and skipping every other column as 1 iteration, with the starting column declared as an awk variable (Just a thought I have no way of knowing how to do)

Thank you for looking over this problem.

Comment: what is an iteration count?

Comment: I believe what Thomas means by "iteration count" is the total number of columns to print out per-line. So that is why there is no column 2 in the sample output.

Comment: your desired results for Mission 1 stop with column/field #4; where is column/field #2? (assuming column/field #1 is the null string squeezed in between '^' and the first '@'); or is that what you mean by 'iteration count', ie, 'iteration count' == 'number of columns to output' ???

Comment: Unimportant beat me to the response. To clarify, I'm looking for five columns of output; Mission 1 starting with the last column and Mission 2 starting with the next  to last. Both Missions are every other column of output.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought a separator character could make that much difference but good grief that example's hard to read with those `@`s as separators! Using `,`s would have been much clearer FWIW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are certainly more elegant ways to do this, but I am not really an `awk` person:

Part 1:

```
awk -F@ '{ x = ""; for (f = NF; f > (NF - 5 * 2); f -= 2) { x = x ? $f "@" x : $f ; } print x }' file.csv
```

Output:

```
2@2.25@1.5@1@3.25
9@5.25@4@3@3.25
4@.2@.5@1@3.75
8@13.75@13@8.5@6
1@.2@.5@3@6.5
7@10.25@10.5@11@12.75
```

Part 2:

```
awk -F@ '{ x = ""; for (f = NF - 1; f > (NF - 5 * 2); f -= 2) { x = x ? $f "@" x : $f ; } print x }' file.csv
```

Output:

```
SayWhat@4@3@1@1
Smarty@6@5@4@2
IfYouLike@1@1@2@3
LaughingHard@8@8@6@4
AtFunny@3@2@3@5
PunchLines@7@7@8@6
```

The literal `5` in each of those is your "number of iterations."

Answer (score 3):

Sample data:

```
$ cat mission.dat
@12@SayWhat@2@4@2.25@3@1.5@1@1@1@3.25
@7@Smarty@9@6@5.25@5@4@4@3@2@3.25
@4@IfYouLike@4@1@.2@1@.5@2@1@3@3.75
@3@LaughingHard@8@8@13.75@8@13@6@8.5@4@6
@10@AtFunny@1@3@.2@2@.5@3@3@5@6.5
@8@PunchLines@7@7@10.25@7@10.5@8@11@6@12.75
```

One `awk` solution:

NOTE: OP can add logic to validate the input parameters.

```
$ cat mission
#!/bin/bash
# format: mission { 1 | 2 } { number_of_fields_to_display }
mission=${1}                       # assumes user inputs "1" or "2"
offset=$(( mission - 1 ))           # subtract one to determine awk/NF offset
iteration_count=${2}               # assume for now this is a positive integer

awk -F"@" -v offset=${offset} -v itcnt=${iteration_count} 'BEGIN { OFS=FS }

{ # we will start by counting fields backwards until we run out of fields
  # or we hit "itcnt==iteration_count" fields

  loopcnt=0
  for (i=NF-offset ; i>=0; i-=2)   # offset=0 for mission=1; offset=1 for mission=2
      { loopcnt++
        if (loopcnt > itcnt)
          break
        fstart=i                    # keep track of the field we want to start with
      }

  # now printing our fields starting with field # "fstart";
  # prefix the first printf with a empty string, then each successive
  # field is prefixed with OFS=@

  pfx = ""
  for (i=fstart; i<= NF-offset; i+=2)
      { printf "%s%s",pfx,$i
        pfx=OFS
      }

  # terminate a line of output with a linefeed
  printf "\n"
}
' mission.dat
```

Some test runs:

```
###### mission #1

# with offset/iteration = 4

$ mission 1 4
2.25@1.5@1@3.25
5.25@4@3@3.25
.2@.5@1@3.75
13.75@13@8.5@6
.2@.5@3@6.5
10.25@10.5@11@12.75

#with offset/iteration = 5

$ mission 1 5
2@2.25@1.5@1@3.25
9@5.25@4@3@3.25
4@.2@.5@1@3.75
8@13.75@13@8.5@6
1@.2@.5@3@6.5
7@10.25@10.5@11@12.75

# with offset/iteration = 6

$ mission 1 6
12@2@2.25@1.5@1@3.25
7@9@5.25@4@3@3.25
4@4@.2@.5@1@3.75
3@8@13.75@13@8.5@6
10@1@.2@.5@3@6.5
8@7@10.25@10.5@11@12.75

###### mission #2

# with offset/iteration = 4

$ mission 2 4
4@3@1@1
6@5@4@2
1@1@2@3
8@8@6@4
3@2@3@5
7@7@8@6

# with offset/iteration = 5

$ mission 2 5
SayWhat@4@3@1@1
Smarty@6@5@4@2
IfYouLike@1@1@2@3
LaughingHard@8@8@6@4
AtFunny@3@2@3@5
PunchLines@7@7@8@6

# with offset/iteration = 6;
# notice we pick up field #1 = empty string so output starts with a '@'

$ mission 2 6
@SayWhat@4@3@1@1
@Smarty@6@5@4@2
@IfYouLike@1@1@2@3
@LaughingHard@8@8@6@4
@AtFunny@3@2@3@5
@PunchLines@7@7@8@6
```

Answer (score 1):

this is probably not what you're asking but perhaps will give you an idea.

```
$ awk -F_ -v skip=4 -v endoff=0 '
      BEGIN {OFS=FS} 
            {offset=(NF-endoff)%skip; 
             for(i=offset;i<=NF-endoff;i+=skip) printf "%s",$i (i>=(NF-endoff)?ORS:OFS)}' file

112_116_120
122_126_130
132_136_140
142_146_150
```

you specify the number of skips between columns and the end offset as input variables.  Here, for last column end offset is set to zero and skip column is 4.

For clarity I used the input file

```
$ cat file
_111_112_113_114_115_116_117_118_119_120
_121_122_123_124_125_126_127_128_129_130
_131_132_133_134_135_136_137_138_139_140
_141_142_143_144_145_146_147_148_149_150
```

changing `FS` for your format should work.